# Are there easy ways to rotate a video in DroidCam 180 degrees?

Tags: 22.04, droidcam

I have Ubuntu 22.04.
I installed the latest version of DroidCam from the official website:
https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/

Logged into Google Meet. There the video is displayed horizontally, but the phone stands vertically.
On the same page I found a solution - in the item “HD Mode – Change webcam resolution”:

```
sudo rmmod v4l2loopback_dc
sudo insmod /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media/video/v4l2loopback-dc.ko width=WIDTH height=HEIGHT
```

I did it, now the image is shown vertically, but upside down. I'm trying to rotate it using the buttons in DroidCam, but image starts to show horizontally. In addition, the image is separated and overlap on each other after rotation.

I couldn't find a simple solution. I asked ChatGPT. It gave me the answer:

> ...But unfortunately, at the time of my last update (January 2022),
> there was no support for rotating an image 180 degrees directly
> through the v4l2loopback options. This usually requires the use of
> additional video processing tools such as ffmpeg. You can use ffmpeg
> to rotate the image 180 degrees and transfer it to the v4l2loopback
> device.

That is, in order to just call a colleague, in addition to DroidCam, I also need to run ffmpeg. And switch to virtual camera 2 (ffmpeg takes the image from camera 1, converts it and outputs it to camera 2). Somehow too difficult. Isn't there a simpler option? Seems like an easy task.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to rotate your phone, if possible. There are a few open issues about this on v4l2loopback's github page, but it looks like the linux version hasn't implemented a fully functional rotate/flip option yet.